# Can't install custom R package on macOS

Tags: r, r-package

I am developing an R package on Windows 10 / R 4.2.2

I can build my source package and install it on my machine, and on another Windows 10 machine that runs R 4.1.1. But when I try to install it on macOS with R 4.1.1 I get:

```
Warning in install.packages:
  package 'myPackage.tar.gz' is not available for this version of R
```

I don't understand this message because I can install it on R 4.1.1. I think it has something to do with the fact that it was developed on Windows and I tried to install it on a Mac.

Can someone explain what's the problem and how to solve it?

In the end I want my package to be installable on every OS and in as many R versions as possible.

**Session info:**

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.utf8  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.utf8 
LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] myPackage_0.1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_1.0.10           pillar_1.9.0          compiler_4.2.2        iterators_1.0.14      
tools_4.2.2          
[6] digest_0.6.33         gtable_0.3.3          evaluate_0.21         lifecycle_1.0.3       
tibble_3.2.1         
[11] lattice_0.20-45       pkgconfig_2.0.3       rlang_1.1.0           foreach_1.5.2         
cli_3.6.1            
[16] rstudioapi_0.15.0     yaml_2.3.7            parallel_4.2.2        
ggVennDiagram_1.2.2   xfun_0.39            
[21] fastmap_1.1.1         dplyr_1.1.1           knitr_1.43            admisc_0.33           
generics_0.1.3       
[26] vctrs_0.6.1           locfit_1.5-9.7        grid_4.2.2            tidyselect_1.2.0      
glue_1.6.2           
[31] data.table_1.14.8     R6_2.5.1              hash_2.2.6.2          fansi_1.0.4           
RVenn_1.1.0          
[36] rmarkdown_2.23        limma_3.54.2          ggplot2_3.4.2         edgeR_3.40.2          
magrittr_2.0.3       
[41] scales_1.2.1          codetools_0.2-18      htmltools_0.5.5       testit_0.13           
colorspace_2.1-0     
[46] splitstackshape_1.4.8 utf8_1.2.3            munsell_0.5.0         doParallel_1.0.17     
venn_1.11
```

**DESCRIPTION:**

```
Package: myPackage
Type: Package
Title: Some Title
Version: 0.1.0
Author: Who wrote it
Maintainer: The package maintainer <yourself@somewhere.net>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
Use four spaces when indenting paragraphs within the Description.
License: What license is it under?
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Roxygen: list(r6 = FALSE, markdown = TRUE)
RoxygenNote: 7.2.3
Imports:
  R6,
  utils,
  data.table,
  parallel,
  doParallel,
  foreach,
  dplyr,
  ggVennDiagram,
  testit,
  ggplot2,
  venn,
  base,
  hash,
  stats,
  edgeR,
  splitstackshape,
  statmod
Suggests: 
    knitr,
    rmarkdown
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

Comment: Try `install.packages("myPackage.tar.gz", repos=NULL)`. The warning indicates that it tried to reach out to your defined CRAN repo(s) (set in `options("repos")`), and either the connection(s) failed or it connected and a package named `"myPackage.tar.gz"` does not exist. Of course this latter condition is obvious, no package name includes the literal `.tar.gz`.

Comment: Thanks, will try it as soon as possible and report back